# Get Telerik Grid Row by Row Index

Tags: jquery, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have Grid. On the event "OnRowSelect" I have a function which gets data from the selected row.

```
function loadSelectedRowData(e) {
    var partnerGrid = $("#Grid1").data("tGrid");
    var row = e.row;
    var selectedItem = partnerGrid.dataItem(row);

    $('#Prev').data('rowIndex', row.rowIndex - 1);
    $('#Next').data('rowIndex', row.rowIndex + 1);
}
```

I also have 2 buttons (separated from grid). When I click a button I want to move up and down from the selected row, making the previous or next row selected.
So I add data attribute with row index, that they must select.

But I don't know how to get row by row index.

Maybe something like this :

```
grid.$rows().each(function(){
if (this.index(e.row) == dataIndex) { //select this row
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as Telerik is not supporting any more this version is really hard to find good solution for this case.

As a quick solution you can try to do something like this:

```
function selectRowThatYouWant(gridid,rowIndex) {
        var tr = jQuery("#" + gridid + "tbody  tr");
        alert(tr.length);
        tr.each(function (index) {
            if (index+1 == rowIndex) {
                jQuery(this).click();
            }
        });
    }
```